# How do I make a bitmap version of a WMF file that is loaded into a TImage.Picture and move that to a TSpeedButton.Glyph

Tags: delphi, canvas, delphi-xe2

For the sake of a minimal complete question, I have a WMF file loaded into a `TImage` control on a form. This control contains the property Picture, which is a `TPicture` type.  I am trying to "rasterize" the WMF file that I loaded into the TImage, and store that into a `TSpeedButton.Glyph`.

What is interesting about this process is I am able to use this technique to create a resolution independent custom control (a button in my case) that will redraw its glyph for any resolution you like.

In real world usage, I would not have a TImage or a TSpeedButton, but this question is fundamentally about the process of moving content from `TPicture` to a `TBitmap`.

Here is the relevant semi-working code:

```
procedure CopyBitmap(  Source:TImage;  DestSpeedButton:TSpeedButton );
var
   bmp: TBitmap;
begin
   bmp:=TBitmap.Create;
   try
     // note: with WMF loaded, Source.Picture.Bitmap.Width and Height are 0.
     bmp.Width := Source.Width; // originally I had Source.Picture.Bitmap.Width, which didn't work.
     bmp.Height := Source.Height; //because Source.Picture.Bitmap.Height, doesn't work.
     bmp.Canvas.Draw(0,0, Source.Picture.Graphic );
     DestSpeedButton.Glyph:=bmp;
   finally
     bmp.Free;
   end;
end;
```

Is this the correct approach? Why does the image invert during copy?

A sample WMF file, the exact file I'm using, is found [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B07SrKpE8ErmeFcxQ3ZVLWtWWEE/edit?usp=sharing).

[image]

Comment: A meta file typically does not have a background. So you need to paint the background on the raster image. You don't do that.

Comment: I guess I want transparency, so I should paint a `clFuchsia` brush.

Comment: Fill it with fuchsia or something that ain't black or white, before painting the metafile, and see what happens then.

Comment: Feel free to convert that comment to an answer. I'll add my own sample code updated.

Comment: Does it solve the problem? If so, feel free to write your own answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks David, for suggesting that I draw the background. This works.

Note that in production I would change the code below to use `Vcl.GraphUtils` helper called `ScaleImage` as the results are much prettier. See the second code sample.

```
// Quick and Dirty : No sub-pixel anti-aliasing.
// Also does not modifies Source, so set Source's size before you 
// call this. 
procedure CopyBitmap(  Source:TImage;  DestSpeedButton:TSpeedButton );
var
   bmp: TBitmap;
begin
   bmp:=TBitmap.Create;
   try
     bmp.SetSize( Source.Width, Source.Height);
     bmp.Canvas.Pen.Style := psClear;
     bmp.Canvas.Brush.Style := bsSolid;
     bmp.Canvas.Brush.Color := clFuchsia;
     bmp.Canvas.Rectangle(0,0, Source.Width+1,Source.Height+1 );
     bmp.Canvas.Draw(0,0, Source.Picture.Graphic );
     bmp.TransparentColor := clFuchsia;
     DestSpeedButton.Glyph:=bmp;
   finally
     bmp.Free;
   end;
end;
```

Alternative that uses more memory, and is using the `TPicture` type instead of `TImage` because in real use I don't even have a `TImage` just a `TPicture`, also this looks nicer. Note that it is written around some custom control of my own design (or yours) that has some property type TBitmap.  You have to substitute your own controls, or change TMyControlWithAGlyph to TSpeedButton if that's what you want to do:

```
// A Bit Better Looking. Uses Vcl.GraphUtils function ScaleImage
procedure CopyBitmap(  Source:TPicture;
                       Dest:TMyControlWithAGlyph;
                       DestType:TCopyDestTypeEnum;
                       AWidth,AHeight:Integer;
                       DoInvert:Boolean;
                       TransparentColor:TColor=clFuchsia );
var
   bmp,bmpFullSize: TBitmap;
   ARect:TRect;
   ScaleAmount:Double;
begin
   if not Assigned(Source) then
      exit;
   if not Assigned(Dest) then
      exit;

   if not Assigned(Source.Graphic) then
      exit;


   bmp:=TBitmap.Create;
   bmpFullSize := TBitmap.Create;
   try
     bmpFullSize.SetSize(  Source.Width, Source.Height );
     bmpFullSize.PixelFormat := pf24bit;
     bmpFullSize.Canvas.Pen.Style := psClear;
     bmpFullSize.Canvas.Brush.Style := bsSolid;
     bmpFullSize.Canvas.Brush.Color := TransparentColor;
     bmpFullSize.Canvas.Rectangle(0,0, Source.Width+1,Source.Height+1 );
     bmpFullSize.Canvas.Draw(0,0, Source.Graphic );


     bmp.SetSize( AWidth, AHeight);
     bmp.PixelFormat := pf24bit;

     // Vcl.GraphiUtil version needs a floating point scale.
     ScaleAmount := AWidth / Source.Width;
     ScaleImage(bmpFullSize,bmp,ScaleAmount );

     // This lets me have a white icon and turn it black if I want to
     // or vice versa
     if DoInvert then
       InvertBitmap(bmp); 

     if DestType=DestLargeGlyph then
     begin
          Dest.LargeGlyph := bmp;
     end
     else
     begin
          Dest.Glyph:=bmp;
     end;
   finally
     bmp.Free;
     bmpFullSize.Free;
   end;
end;
```

The above code also calls this little helper:

```
function InvertBitmap(ABitmap: TBitmap): TBitmap;
var
   x, y: Integer;
   ByteArray: PByteArray;
begin
   ABitmap.PixelFormat := pf24Bit;
   for y := 0 to ABitmap.Height - 1 do
   begin
      ByteArray := ABitmap.ScanLine[y];
      for x := 0 to ABitmap.Width * 3 - 1 do
      begin
         ByteArray[x] := 255 - ByteArray[x];
      end;
   end;
   Result := ABitmap;
end;
```

Comment: Bitmap.SetSize is a useful convenience FWIW

Comment: If I do it this way it creates the bitmap twice?

Comment: I doubt it. It just reads better with a single method call to assign both. When was the last time you sized one but not the other?

Comment: True. Also I had a bit of a pen-canvas glitch. Fixed that too.

Comment: If this works as expected you should accept this answer.

Comment: I have to wait 48 hours! :-)